# Installing RVO2 for Python, problems with Cython

Tags: python, cython

First, I have to mention that I am a beginner, so if I miss something obvious, please be lenient.

I try to install this version of the RVO2-algorithm:

https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/Python-RVO2

When I try to install the requirements `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\cm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a6tbh0p6\\cython_5705f9aae20248d2b5e6
8294cdd24a9f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a6tbh0p6\\cython_5705f9aae20248d2b5e68294cdd24a9f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__f
ile__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-zxh85mhl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\cm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\Cython'
     cwd: C:\Users\CM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6tbh0p6\cython_5705f9aae20248d2b5e68294cdd24a9f\
```

Also, there is the complete output written, of which I think only the last part could be important:

```
skipping 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6tbh0p6\cython_5705f9aae20248d2b5e68294cdd24a9f\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I am confused because I use Pycharm, so why does it ask for Visual Studio?

I use Python 3.7 on a Win10 PC

Comment: It wants the C/C++ compiler from visual studio, not the editor from visual studio

Comment: Some Python libraries include code written in C or C++ and installing them will try to build them from source. You can either set up a C compiler, or just grab a pre-compiled binary from a source you trust. The library takes care of the interface between the Python and C code, so don't worry about having to do anything with it, once its built and installed

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can give the update, that i changed from Windows to Ubuntu as OS and now it works out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run RVO2, those requirements are not necessary. You need only cmake and Cython. You can try get it by pip.

```
pip install cmake 
pip install Cython
```

Then you should run

```
python3 setup.py build
```

After successful build, run

```
python3 setup.py install
```